# Gauss-Jordan Algorithm underdetermined equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$Ax=b$ with $A$ more columns than rows.

If I apply Gauß Jordan algorithm, I get a diagonal matrix, where I can read off one solution. But don't I loose some solutions, because there are many solutions, because of the underdetermined equation system?

Comment: You have to let some of the variables just be variables and write the general solution in terms of them.

Comment: so i can't mix row and columns operation otherwise i change the kernel solution space?

Comment: If you have a specific matrix please post it.

Comment: No i don't have a specific one. I just want to know in general.

Comment: I tought the gauß-jordan steps are multiplication by elementary matrices and don't change the kernel. But some steps in gauß jordan seem to destory solutions.